# Mule: Unable to locate .json file when Deployable archive move to CloudHub

Tags: jersey, mule, cloudhub

Could someone please help. I have read you recommendation but not able to understand that. I have to read one json file in cloudhub.

In my local repositories I have kept the .json file in location `test/src/main/resources/input.json`. And reading this from Java Class

**`private static final String jsonFilePath = "src\main\resources\input.json";`**

OR **`private static final String jsonFilePath = "input.json";`**

When `.json` file is in root folder of project

```
byte[] jsonFile = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(jsonFilePath));
```

Not able to find the "`input.json`" file when `MDA moved to cloud hub` and I am getting file not found exception in `cloudhub`. when I printed all my files in my project directory, I am not able to search any specific files from my project in cloudHub.

***I have printed all files in my project directory structure in cloudHub but I not able to find "`input.json`". Could you please suggest.***

> 21:53:30.952 05/26/2015 INFO file:/home/ion-mule/muleProperties.dump
>
> 21:53:30.952 05/26/2015 INFO file:/home/ion-mule/muleLauncher.log
>
> 21:53:30.953 05/26/2015 INFO directory:/home/ion-mule/.ssh
>
> 21:53:30.953 05/26/2015 INFO file:/home/ion-mule/.bash_profile
>
> 21:53:30.954 05/26/2015 INFO file:/home/ion-mule/.ssh/authorized_keys
>
> 21:53:30.954 05/26/2015 INFO file:/home/ion-mule/.bash_logout
>
> 21:53:30.954 05/26/2015 INFO file:/home/ion-mule/muleMonitor.log
>
> 21:53:30.955 05/26/2015 INFO file:/home/ion-mule/.bashrc

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load your application resources from the classpath, not from a path that is related to the original project structure.

Files in `src\main\resources` end-up at the root of the classpath in the packaged application. So the following should provide you with the file's content as a stream:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("input.json");
```